# Working with Dojo Data Grid results in "Uncaught Error: TableStore: invalid parameter"

Tags: dojo, xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a Dojo Data Grid that I'm implementing in XPages that contains a lot of data.

When I attempt to call exportGrid on the Data Grid, it generally works well. However, it seems that past a certain point of data, I'm unable to export the grid.

When I run the export, I get the error:
xspClientDojo.js:5 Uncaught Error: TableStore: invalid parameter

This appears to be occurring during the "getValue" function, specifically in the "_assertHasAttribute" function call.

I'm not huge on Dojo debugging but am looking for any advice to point me toward a solution or a method to further debug the issue.

Thanks for any help you might be able to provide.

Answer (score 0):

After some further tinkering with debugger I was able to discover what was happening.

The rest service that was serving the data grid was based on a Notes View. In that Notes View, there was a column that was occasionally returning an error. When the notes view returns an error, the column is omitted from the rest service. Therefore, when that row is queried for data, it does not contain the named Attribute.

Ideally I would expect the rest service to contain the error text or a null value, but this is what leads to this error.

Comment: You could contemplate using a custom rest service to handle that